# How to get SVM accuracy achieved by train_auto() in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, svm

The SVM framework in OpenCV has a functrion called `train_auto`:

> The method trains the SVM model automatically by choosing the optimal
>   parameters C, gamma, p, nu, coef0, degree from CvSVMParams. Parameters
>   are considered optimal when **the cross-validation estimate of the test
>   set error** is minimal.

Is it possible to get (and, for example, print) this error or related accuracy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I have investigated the source of OpenCV and **answer for version 2.49 is no**.
`train_auto` store accuracy in variable `min_error`, which is local.

On the other hand: I'm not sure if it hasn't been changed in newer releases.